# api data directly insert into PostgreSQL database with python

Tags: json, database, python-3.x, postgresql

## main.py

```
import json, urllib.request, requests
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values


# Retrieve Json Data from Within API

url = "https://datahead.herokuapp.com/api/employeers/"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())


# ***** connect to the db *******
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='datahead' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='datahead'")
except:
    print("I am unable to connect to the database")

# cursor
cur = conn.cursor()

fields = [
    'id', #integer
    'name', #varchar
    'log_date', #date
    'log_time', #timestamp
    'login', #timestamp
    'logout' #timestamp
]

for item in data:
    my_data = [item[field] for field in fields]
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO employee VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    cur.execute(insert_query, tuple(my_data))
    conn.commit()

# close the cursor
cur.close()

# close the connection
conn.close()
```

please visit my api data format https://datahead.herokuapp.com/api/employeers/

[image: Error Through]

Will it change here timestamp type, if yes so which data type i've to use?
Line 56 what happened?

[image: PGadmin type]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `login_time` should be of type `time without time zone` in PostgresSQL.

But you would probably be better off using `timestamp with time zone` to represent date and time together.

Comment: in my login, logout and log_time i used "timestamp without time zone" and in this case only i want to represent my time that's why without timezone used and doesn't work.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUC7z.png please visit this image and here if i use with timezone then i can't calculation may be.

Comment: There is too little English in your last comment for me to understand. Also, text is better than images.

Comment: Yeah i've solved that. have to use there time instead of timestamp. Thanks @Laurenz Albe